# jQuery UI Draggable, Sortable - Disallow dragging element

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, draggable, jquery-ui-sortable

this is the script I'm using:

```
    $(".nav .row").draggable({
    connectToSortable: ".demo",
    helper: "clone",
    handle: ".drag",
    drag: function (e, t) {
        t.helper.width(400)
    },
    stop: function (e, t) {
        $(".demo .column").sortable({
            opacity: .35,
            connectWith: ".column"
        })
    }
});
```

Basically what it does is that it allows dragging new rows and allows dragging elements inside columns inside these rows.

Here is an example output:

```
<div class='demo'>
     <div class='row'>
          <div class='column'>
          </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

The problem with it is that it allows dragging another row inside that column class, I want to prevent this from happening, this is what happens:

```
<div class='demo'>
     <div class='row'>
          <div class='column'>
               <div class='row'>
                    <div class='column'>
                    </div>
               </div>
          </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Can anyone give me some suggestions how I could prevent this from happening?

Comment: Can you create a fiddle? What you basically need to do is define what is droppable (by class if you want) and when something is moved to where its at the end of its line take off the droppable class

Answer (score 0):

It's happening because `$(".nav .row")` selects all elements with a class of `.row` within nav container. You could add another class name to target specific rows, for example:

```
<div class='demo'>
     <div class='row dragabble'>
          <div class='column'>
          </div>
     </div>
</div>

$(".nav .draggable").draggable({
    connectToSortable: ".demo",
    helper: "clone",
    handle: ".drag",
    drag: function (e, t) {
        t.helper.width(400)
    },
    stop: function (e, t) {
        $(".demo .column").sortable({
            opacity: .35,
            connectWith: ".column"
        })
    }
});
```

Comment: The thing is there isn't just one row available, there's unlimited amount of rows available and ideally they would be all under .demo not inside .column. So adding class wouldn't help me here.

Comment: You can apply 'draggable' class to unlimited amount of rows, which would target only those rows and skip the ones without 'draggable' class. If you want to target the rows inside 'column' div, then change jQuery selector to '$(".column .draggable")'. HTML would look like this: '<div class="column"><div class="row draggable"></div></div>'

Comment: As per explained problem "The problem with it is that it allows dragging another row inside that column class, I want to prevent this from happening, this is what happens:" Tomas is correct.